# Python program not running using Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Can anyone help me to find the error in this program?
I try to run this from the Google App engine but all I see is a blank page.
Though when I remove the line texty=convert_rot(user_enter, "") and use user_enter instead of texty in the next line, then the code works but then I am not able to use the function 'converter_rot' which is the main part of the program.

```
import webapp2
import cgi
form="""
<form method="post">
    Enter the text to be converted to ROT13:
    <br><br>
<input type="text" name="texty" value="%(texty)s">
<br>
<div style="color:red">%(error)s</div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>"""
def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)

def converter_rot(aa,w):
    for i in aa:
        x=ord(i)
        if i>='a' and i<='z':
            x=ord(i)+13
            if x>=122:
                x=x-25
        if i>='A' and i<='Z':
            x=ord(i)+13
            if x>=90:
                x=x-25      
        w=w+chr(x)
    return w
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, error="", texty=""):
        self.response.write(form % {"error":error, "texty":escape_html(texty)})
    def get(self):
        self.write_form()
    def post(self):
        user_enter = self.request.get('texty')
            texty=converter_rot(user_enter,"")
        self.write_form("",texty)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs in the appengine dashboard?

Comment: It says return w is not indented correctly. I don't understand it is at the same indent as the for loop in the function def converter_rot

Comment: i got it. Thanks for the help. and Xcode is pretty bad for indenting i figured out